# Query to search a keyword on an entire table

Tags: sqlite

I have the following table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uBx0.jpg

When I execute the query:

SELECT Description, Solution, ReportBy from KMS where Description or Effect or Cause or Check1 or Solution or ReportBy like '%test%'

and this is the result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuMHy.jpg

I could expect the lanes 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10 to be the result, what I am doing wrong?

Regards,
FMendonça

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query

```
SELECT Description, Solution, ReportBy 
from KMS 
where Description
or Effect
or Cause 
or Check1 
or Solution 
or ReportBy like '%test%'
```

will only return results for rows that have

- `ReportBy like %test%'`
- `1` in any of the other columns

That is because `where Description` is essentially a boolean test. If you want to check values in multiple columns, you must check each column seperately, like:

```
WHERE Description like '%test%'
OR Effect like '%test%'
.
.
OR ReportBy like '%test%'
```